# Declaring a global variable inside a function

Tags: php, cookies, global-variables

I have two PHP files.  In the first I set a cookie based on a `$_GET` value, and then call a function which then sends this value on to the other file.  This is some code which I'm using in **join.php**:

```
include('inc/processJoin.php');
setcookie("site_Referral", $_GET['rid'], time()+10000);
$joinProc = new processJoin();
$joinProc->grabReferral($_COOKIE["site_Referral"]);
```

The other file (**processJoin.php**) will then send this value (among others) to further files which will process and insert the data into the database.

The problem I'm having is that when the `grabReferral()` function in **processJoin.php** is called, the `$referralID` variable isn't being defined on a global scale - other functions in `processJoin.php` can't seem to access it to send to other files/processes.

I've tried this in **processJoin.php**:

```
grabReferral($rid) {
   global $ref_id;
   $ref_id = $rid;
}

someOtherFunction() {
   sendValue($ref_id);
}
```

But the someOtherFunction can't seem to access or use the `$ref_id` value.  I've also tried using `define()` to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why oh why are you using global variables? There is almost always a better solution.

Comment: *(should read)* [Global in Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527)

Comment: @MattBall: Agreed. And, based on variable name, I would venture to say `define('REF_ID',$id);` and `if(defined('REF_ID'))...` are a better solution.

Comment: @Brad no, it wouldnt. Avoid the global scope.

Comment: @BradChristie When I use `define('REF_ID',$rid)` in the `grabReferral()` function, I can't access the constant in the `someotherFunction()` function. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Jamie: See the [answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355644/declaring-a-global-variable-inside-a-function/5355680#5355680) and use `$GLOBALS` instead (but avoid it if you can).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you have to define the global var in the second function as well..

```
// global scope
$ref_id = 1;

grabReferral($rid){
   global $ref_id;
   $ref_id = $rid;
}

someOtherFunction(){
    global $ref_id;
    sendValue($ref_id);
}
```

felix

Answer (score 25):

personally, I would recommend the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) super variable.

```
function foo(){
  $GLOBALS['foobar'] = 'foobar';
}
function bar(){
  echo $GLOBALS['foobar'];
}
foo();
bar();
```

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/08dxn)**

Comment: it's $GLOBALS, no underscore.

Comment: @marcB Indeed. I'm used to wiring it out for $_POST/$_GET. Good catch, thank you.

Comment: @MarcB: Yea, don't I know it. `MYSQL_BOTH` = mysql_fetch_array, `CURLOPT_HEADER` = curl_setopt, ..., `PHP_URL_HOST` = parse_url? wtf? ;p

Comment: as of PHP 8 write access to `$GLOBALS` is no longer allowed

Comment: @paolo Write access is "limited" not "no longer allowed". See more details on restrictions [here](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/GLOBALS-restrictions)

Answer (score 13):

This is a simple and working code to initialize global variable from a function :

```
function doit()
{
    $GLOBALS['val'] = 'bar';
}
doit();
echo $val;
```

Gives the output as :

```
bar
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works.

```
<?php

    foo();
    bar();

    function foo()
    {
        global $jabberwocky;
        $jabberwocky="Jabberwocky<br>";

        bar();
    }

    function bar()
    {
        global $jabberwocky;
        echo $jabberwocky;
    }

?>
```

to produce:

Jabberwocky
Jabberwocky

So it seems that a variable first declared as global inside a function and then initalised inside that function acquires global scope.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` keyword lets you *access* a global variable, not create one. Global variables are the ones created in the outermost scope (i.e. not inside a function or class), and are not accessible inside function unless you declare them with `global`.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  If you call a function `function foo() { global $bar; }` then after the call you will find `array_key_exists('bar',$GLOBALS)` is *true*, i.e. a global variable has been *created*.  (This happens even if `foo()` never assigns a value to it; I tested this on PHP v7.4).  That said, he's probably right about the *intent* behind the `global` keyword, and it's probably a good general recommendation on how to use (or not use) it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: none of this code was tested, but it definitely gets the point across.

Choose a *name* for the variable you want to be available in the global scope.
Within the function, assign a value to the *name* index of the $GLOBALS array.

```
function my_function(){

    //...

    $GLOBALS['myGlobalVariable'] = 42;    //globalize variable

    //...
}
```

Now when you want to access the variable from code running in the global scope, i.e. NOT within a function, you can simply use $ *name* to access it, without referencing the $GLOBALS array.

```
<?php
    //<global scope>

    echo $myGlobalVariable;  //outputs "42"

    //</global scope>
?>
```

To access your global variable from a non-global scope such as a function or an object, you have two options:

1. Access it through the appropriate index of the $GLOBALS array. Ex: `$GLOBALS['myGlobalVariable']`  This takes a long time to type, especially if you need to use the global variable multiple times in your non-global scope.
2. A more concise way is to import your global variable into the local scope by using the 'global' statement. After using this statement, you can reference the global variable as though it were a local variable. Changes you make to the variable will be reflected globally.

   ```
       //<non global scopes>
       function a(){
           //...
           global $myGlobalVariable;
           echo $myGlobalVariable;    // outputs "42"
           //...
        }
       function b(){
           //...
           echo $GLOBALS['myGlobalVariable'];    // outputs "42"
           echo $myGlobalVariable;               // outputs "" (nothing)
                                                 // ^also generates warning - variable not defined
           //...             
       }
       //</non global scopes>
   ```

Please use global variables in any language with caution, especially in PHP.

See the following resources for discussion of global variables:

- http://chateau-logic.com/content/dangers-global-variables-revisited-because-php
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: See also: [http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.249182.18](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.249182.18)

Answer (score 0):

[The visibility of a variable](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

**I hope that helped**

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```