# PHP: declare variable with global scope from inside a function

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring a global variable inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355644/declaring-a-global-variable-inside-a-function)

Is it possible to declare variable with global scope from inside a function?

**NOTE: I don't want to receive the value of a previously declared variable outside the function. But to have the values of the variables declared inside the function working outside the function scope.**

I a way that if I have these variables declared inside a function:

```
function variables($n){
    $a=1+$n;
    $b="This is number +$n";
}
```

I could echo them outside the function:

```
variables(1);
echo $a;
echo '\n';
echo $b;

2
This is number 1
```

I know I could achieve it returning an array from the function but... I'd like to be sure I could otherwise.

I saw nothing here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Thanks.

Comment: If you didn't saw there, you must use the scrollbars on the right of your browser window. Or just use your browsers page-search and search for "global".

Comment: What about “By declaring $a and $b global within the function, all references to either variable will refer to the global version.”?

Comment: Global Variables are not good at all.. I highly recommend against even the idea of using them, as it will hit something in your app which you won't anticipate.

Comment: @Frederico: Don't discriminate global variables, they just do their job ;)

Comment: Thanks God not everyone "sinks" the "shame" way, I mean: "thinks" the "same" way :-)

Comment: although yes, you should stay away from global variables, there are places that they help. we have a class that handles our database connection. the class is instantiated to a single var and database is connected to in an auto_prepend file. There are two ways to get the instance into a function to run a query, pass as an argument or use global. I prefer the latter so I don't have to add the instance to every call of the function. Not ideal, but it was setup before I started.

Comment: In a small script this helps to write less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read elsewhere about why globals are bad, so I'll just stick to the question. You can use the [`global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#example-89) for this. The same applies if you want to *read* a global from inside a function.

```
function variables($n){
    global $a,$b;
    $a=1+$n;
    $b="This is number +$n";
}
```

Comment: Hey!!! it works!!! I thought the global declaration was only to receive variables values from outside of the function scope!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: By the way, @grossvogel, thank you for helping me to clarify my doubt without prejudice. Quite different from the "square pins" around.