# Programmatically declare globals in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, global, declaration

Plain and simple like the title says - Is there any way to programmatically declare globals inside a function in PHP? For example, from an array of strings (which are the global variables names)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7769995/5788489

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

Comment: Guys I know how to declare a global variable that's not what I'm asking, I'll edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you add variables to the `$GLOBALS` array they are then globally available like any other global.

```
function add_globals($arr)
{
    foreach ( $arr as $idx => $name ) {
        $GLOBALS[$name] = $idx;
    }
}

$names = array('aa','bb');
add_globals($names);
echo $aa.PHP_EOL;
echo $bb.PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT

```
0
1
```

I am just using the index of the $names array as a value for each new global, you could use anything