# php function global variable boolean not working

Tags: php, scope, global-variables

Why isn't the "yes you are in check function" printed?

file.php

```
 $debug = true;

 function check() {

     global $debug;

     error_log("in check function");

     if ($debug) {
         error_log(" yes you are in check function"); 
     }
}
```

SO when check() is called, the output is ONLY:

in check function

how can that be? why isn't the 2nd error log line printed?

Comment: Can't reproduce https://3v4l.org/VGZqF

Comment: Make sur all of this is done at a global scope otherwise define $debug gloabally before initilialising it (global $debug; $debug = true;)

Comment: thanks Nick, but it's not working on my server, in my code????  I was positive I was correct :)  but????

thanks Jordan, are you saying to use global twice? On the outside and inside the function?

Comment: Answer provided here might be relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5355688/8448583 States that the `global` keyword is used to access global variables, not create them. If that's the case, you don't have a global.

Comment: If this code is inside another function therefore isn't in a global scope then you would need to add "gobal $debug;" before setting it to true. Beside that the only other possibilty I could think of would be that the debug variable is used somewhere else.